# Too many push-notifications (Parse.com)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

Using Parse.com for one of my iOS apps, aready on the appStore, I recently experienced a large number of remote notifications sent to users, in a rather short time.
The number of notifications sent in such a short time cannot be due to the normal functionning of the app.

What could make such a thing happen?

I made an Export Data on the same day. Could that be the cause?
I also modified one record, on one of the tables, but that only explains one push notification.
I was also working on the app, preparing for a future version, but do not think I did anything to fire a great number of notifications, or any notification at all.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export Data has nothing to do with push notifications - that is not the cause.

Look through all of your push notifications that you sent. You can see your push records by going to the 'Push' tab on the Parse.com dashboard. It will allow you to see who was send each of the pushes and when they were sent, along with the JSON payload.

I would recommend taking a hard look at your push notification code to ensure you do not have an accidental loop, as that sounds like the most likely culprit.